# cmake error: cc fails because no input files

Tags: cmake, llvm

hello I just installed cmake 3.6.2 (the one that comes with cygwin) and I got an error message trying to build llvm, saying that the build failed because cc was unable to find the input file. I've seen lots of postings about a similar problem but in this case, cc is right - the input file does not in fact exist, as I confirmed by checking the directory CMakeTmp. I don't have any spaces in the cmake installation directory tree which is typically the problem. So it looks like cmake has screwed up somewhere. Any ideas?

```
$ cmake $C/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Haskell Platform/8.4.3/mingw/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Haskell Platform/8.4.3/mingw/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Haskell Platform/8.4.3/mingw/bin/cc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Haskell
  Platform/8.4.3/mingw/bin/cc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_d77a9/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Haskell Platform/8.4.3/mingw/bin/cc.exe" -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  cc.exe: error:
  /cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c:
  No such file or directory

  cc.exe: fatal error: no input files

  compilation terminated.

  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/build.make:66:
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_d77a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_d77a9/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:50 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/llvm-7.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

So I installed cmake from the cmake website and that works fine, so it definitely looks like a problem with the cygwin cmake. I would report this bug to cygwin if there was a way to do so